# List all products with special price

Tags: product-collection, magento-2.0.7, special-price

I need to create a page which lists all special products (with active special price). How can I do this?

Comment: You can follow below link: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11778/create-category-page-which-displays-all-special-price-products

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I did it

```
    $objectManager   = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

    $visibleProducts = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds();
    $collection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection')->setVisibility($visibleProducts);

    $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection);

    $stockFilter = $objectManager->create('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock');
    $stockFilter->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);

    $collection    
        ->addAttributeToFilter(
            'special_price',
            ['gt'=>0], 'left'
        )->addAttributeToFilter(
            'special_from_date',['or' => [ 0 => ['date' => true, 
                                                'to' => date('Y-m-d',time()).' 23:59:59'],
                                          1 => ['is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr(
                                             'null'
                                         )],]], 'left'
        )->addAttributeToFilter(
            'special_to_date',  ['or' => [ 0 => ['date' => true,
                                               'from' => date('Y-m-d',time()).' 00:00:00'],
                                         1 => ['is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr(
                                             'null'
                                         )],]], 'left'
        );
```

Comment: How can we display this products in cms page we have created?

Comment: Hello @Anna, this working for me, but when I enabled the flat catalog this is showing the following MySQL error:
Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.special_from_date' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT FLOOR((ROUND((e.min_price) * 1, 2)) / 100) + 1 AS `range`, COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `catalog_product_index_price` AS `e`

Answer (score 0):

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $productCollection */
        $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');    

        $min =10; $max =1000;

        $productCollection->addFieldToFilter('special_price', ['lt' => $min, 'gt' => $max]);

        $productCollection->load();
```

Comment: why the $min/$max limit?

Comment: @YehiaA.Salam I know it not compulsory, just added for the limit